# object MotorLatentCommandCursor can't be used in 'await' expression

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, tornado-motor

use motor in Tornado to connect mongodb

i created a motor connect

```
import motor.motor_tornado
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient('mongodb://xxx')

class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return client['realtime-test']

class Account(BaseHandler):
    async def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        all_user = await self.db.account.aggregate([
            {'$match': {'status': 1}},
            {'$group': {'_id':''}}
        ])
        print(all_user)
```

when i got started ,i got this message:
"object MotorLatentCommandCursor can't be used in 'await' expression"

idk why ~ it's seems like nothing wrong

Answer (score 5):

The [`aggregate()`](https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-tornado/motor_collection.html#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCollection.aggregate) method returns a cursor which you can use in a loop. You can't use it in an `await` statement because it's not an awaitable object.

You'd use it something like this:

```
async def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
    cursor = self.db.account.aggregate([
        {'$match': {'status': 1}},
        {'$group': {'_id':''}}
    ])

    all_user = []

    async for doc in cursor: 
        all_user.append(doc)

    print(all_user)
```

Comment: sorry.but i also have a question. if i need a result list, i can just use one I/O in python & mongodb .so when i use motor with async for , i need to get each one in each for loop and it will need a lots of I/O for python & motor. how can i make it better

Comment: @Natee You don't have to worry about that. Because MongoDB returns query results in large batches (of 101 documents by default). So, the `async for` loop will do only a single I/O for 101 docs and so on. Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/#cursor-batches

Answer (score 3):

by adding to_list().
this works for me

```
all_user = await self.db.account.aggregate([
            {'$match': {'status': 1}},
            {'$group': {'_id':''}}]).to_list(None)
```

Answer (score 0):

In official documentation said: An object that can be used in an await expression. Can be a coroutine or an object with an **await**() method.
you can get more information from PEP 492: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for

also you can use asgiref to wrap your function:

```
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
import motor.motor_tornado
from tornado.web import RequestHandler
client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient('mongodb://xxx')

class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):
    @property
    def db(self):
        return client['realtime-test']

class Account(BaseHandler):
    async def get(self,*args,**kwargs):
        all_user = await sync_to_async(self.db.account.aggregate)([
            {'$match': {'status': 1}},
            {'$group': {'_id':''}}
        ])
        print(all_user)
```